# xsl modulus issue not displaying html inside for each if clauses

Tags: xslt

Here's my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/articles/article">
     <xsl:if test="(pos() mod 5)">
         // display some html here
      </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Doesn't seem to work. The page just hangs. Not quite sure whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath defines a function named `position()` but not one named `pos()`.

Comment: What do you want to check exactly, `position() mod 5` is a numeric expression giving a numeric value while you use it for the `test` attribute where you would usually use a boolean expression like e.g. `test="position() mod 5 = 0"`.